# How to send custom data through pusher webhook

Tags: laravel, webhooks, pusher

So, I am working on the API and a website where I am sending a request from my backend server to that API and my API gives response through PUSHER to the front-end directly and once the front-end receives all the responses from the pusher in contacts the back-end so that the database can be updated. Now instead of receiving the final update from the front-end i want the pusher to directly contact my backend so that the database can be updated

So I came across the webhooks functionality that pusher provides in order to communicate to the backend server.Pusher generates only 3 events viz. channel existence, presence and client event. But I want the pusher to generate webhook request when the API message is being pushed into the pusher, so that I can access the response for storing into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusher does not provide this functionality. WebHooks are designed to inform your application of changes to the state of channels, not as means of arbitrary communication from Pusher to your server.

On top of this, it sounds like you want to notify your server once the client has received all events. Pusher does not know exactly *when* the client receives events. The only place where you can be sure the client has received an event is on the client itself.

Your current solution of sending a request directly from your client to the server sounds like the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

yes that's true, but pusher emits events that pipedream listens to and communicates to your endpoint. in the end it's a solution that works very well. of course we don't forget our events and listener in the back-end [pipedream link](https://pipedream.com/)